# Log file size is huge

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

We have one database and we do lot many transactios per day, so the log file size growing too much, and i have tried shrinking it but its not reducing..

What shall i do to reduce the log file size. (We do too many inserts)

Thanks
Srinivas

Comment: What's your backup model, full or simple?

Answer (score 3):

You have a database [with "Full" recovery model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175987.aspx) and no log backups running.

Either set to simple recovery model or set up log backups. There are no other *correct* choices (such as shrinking or truncating). The link above has links to other articles too.

Comment: I have changed the recovery model to Simple, and now how can i reduce the size of the db

Comment: If you're in a production database with a "lot of transactions per day" I wouldn't recommend arbitrarily putting it into simple recovery. Make sure you know that you're putting your data at risk by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

After you set your database recovery mode to simple run the following query:

```
 use databasename; 
 CHECKPOINT;
 DBCC SHRINKFILE ('databasename_log');
```

where databasename_log is the filename of the physical transaction log file