# SQL Server 2008 log file size is large and growing quickly

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

Most of the time users will hit the database to read news. There are very few number of queries executed under transactions. 95% of the database hits would be for read-only purposes.

My database log files size is growing 1 GB per day. Even if I shrink the database, the log file size is not decreasing. What could be the reason for growing the log file size more and more? How can I control this? As per my knowledge log file does not increase when we read data from tables.

Any suggestions on how to deal with the log file growing? How can it be kept a manageable or reasonable size? Does this effect performance in any way?

Comment: What is your recovery model? Are you taking full backups?

Comment: seemingly recurring question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140259/log-file-size-is-huge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453858/sql-server-log-file-confusion

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things to consider. What type of backups you do, and what type of backups you need. If you will have the answer to this question you can either switch Recovery Mode to simple or leave it full but then you need to make incremental backups on a daily basis (or whatever makes you happy with log size).

To set your database logging to simple (but only if you do Full Backups of your database!).

1. **Right click** on your database
2. Choose **Properties**
3. Choose **Options**
4. Set Recovery mode to **simple**

This will work and is best if your backup schedule is **Full Backup** every day. Because in such scenario your log won't be trimmed and it will skyrocket (just like in your case).

If you would be using Grandfather&Father&Son backup technique, which means **Monthly Full backup**, **Weekly Full backup**, and then every **day incremental backup**. Then for that you need **Full Recovery Mode**. If 1GB of log per day is still too much you can enable incremental backup per hour or per 15 minutes. This should fix the problem of log growing more and more.

If you run Full Backup every day you can switch it to simple recovery mode and you should be fine without risking your data (if you can leave with possible 1 day of data being lost). If you plan to use incremental then leave it at **Recovery Mode Full**.

Answer (score 1):

Full backups will not help, you must regularly backup the transaction log (as well as the regular database full and differential backups) for it to be emptied. If you are not backing up the log and you are not in simple recovery mode, then your transaction log has every transaction in it since the database was set up. If you have enough action that you are growing by a gig a day, then you may also have large imports or updates affecting many records at once. It is possible you need to be in simple recovery mode where transactions are not recorded individually. Do NOT do that however if you have a mix of data from imports and users. In that case you need to back up the transaction log frequently to be able to keep the size manageable and to a point in time. We backup our transaction log every 15 minutes.

Read about transaction log backups in BOL to see how to fix the mess you have right now. Then get your backups set up and running properly. You need to read and understand this stuff thoroughly before attempting to fix. Right now, you would probably be in a world of hurt if your server failed and you had to recover the database. Transaction log backups are critical to being able to recover properly from a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you backup your database frequently?  You need to perform full- and/or transaction log- backups in order for SQL Server to consider shrinking your log file.

Answer (score 0):

The major reason for the log file large size is due to bulk transaction in DB. To reduce the log file size best option to take the transaction log backup after certain interval of time.